# How i right align images?

Tags: html, css

Im currently trying to recreate a photography website for practice and ive gotten as far as creating the nave bar and the icons. Im having difficulties with my images though. Im wanting to align them to the right of the nav bar and im struggling to figure it out. Please provide me with some feedback. Ill post my source code and the photography website im trying to replicate.
Here is the link to the website: https://www.samalive.co/

```css
body {
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  padding: 70px;
}

header {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.title {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

hr {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  width: 500px;
}


img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h1 class="title">Am Alive</h1>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>City</li>
        <li>Portrait</li>
        <li>Lifestyle</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <hr align="left">
    <div class="footer">
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/because_imalex"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <p>© 2018 Visual Madness.</p>
    </div>
  </div>







  <img src="images/waterfall1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/waterfall2.jpg" alt="">


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have your images set to float left.  I set everything else to float left so it will fall in order or else you can use float:right.

```css
body {
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  padding: 70px;
}

header {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.title {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  float: left;
}

hr {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}


img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h1 class="title">Am Alive</h1>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>City</li>
        <li>Portrait</li>
        <li>Lifestyle</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <hr align="left">
    <div class="footer">
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/because_imalex"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <p>© 2018 Visual Madness.</p>
    </div>
  </div>







  <img src="images/waterfall1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/waterfall2.jpg" alt="">


</body>

</html>
```